# Pull random array member and store index of that member

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables, random

I am doing a task where i need to take 1 member of an array, randomly generate a member from another predefined array, and insert the change to the original array **in that position**.

We have two helper functions:

```
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
  const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] 
}

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
  const newStrand = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    newStrand.push(returnRandBase())
  }
  return newStrand
}
```

And this is my unfinished object so far:

```
const pAqueorFactory = (num, arr) => {
  const newObj = {
    _specimenNum: num,
    _dna: arr,
    get specimenNum() {
      return this._specimenNum;
    },
    get dna() {
      return this._dna;
    },
    mutate() {
      //Select random base in obj array
      let randObjBase = arr.indexOf(this.dna[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)]);
      console.log(randObjBase);
      console.log(arr[randObjBase]);
      //Generate random base from helper function
      let genBase = returnRandBase();
      //While generated base is same as selected base, generate a new one.
      while (randObjBase === genBase) {
        genBase = returnRandBase();
      }
      randObjBase = genBase;
      return randObjBase;
    }
  };

  return newObj
}
```

And then the calls:

```
let arrToDisp = pAqueorFactory(1, mockUpStrand());
console.log(arrToDisp.dna);
console.log(arrToDisp.mutate());
```

The problem I am facing is within the `mutate()` method:

```
//Select random base in obj array
      let randObjBase = arr.indexOf(this.dna[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)]);
      console.log(randObjBase);
      console.log(arr[randObjBase]);
```

`let randObjBase` stores of the index of a randomly selected member, but due to how `indexOf()` works, a random member will be picked but will only return the **first instance** of it. So when making changes and reapplying it to the array it may not apply it to the original position if that makes sense.

If I opt to not using indexOf, then the code will simply pass the value into `randObjBase` but I won't have the index of which to put it back. Any suggestions you guys may have?

---

AFTERTHOUGHT: While writing this I just had a thought that I should break down the process even further and generate a random number and store it, **then** use that number to perform operations. I am going to try that now, but I wish to still learn from others that may or may not have a more effective approach to this.

EDIT: Separating the generation of the index worked! Hopefully reading this can help someone else out